# iphone development: controlling UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have `UITableView`. I mark the selected cell with checkmarks and remove the checkmark if it gets selected again. I have a UIBarButtonItem which is a "next" button and it is disabled by default.

My question is the next button has to be enabled if at least one `UITableViewCell` has checkmark. How can I control all the cells whether at least one of them has checkmark or not.

Comment: Are you using custom UITableViewCell or UITableView Accessories?

Comment: @Rushi UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Comment: Can you show us the code how you are selecting and deselecting this check marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you "just" use a bool-variable which gets set to true when the cell is selected and false when it is not? Then check for that every time you reload tableview and disable/enable next button accordingly?

Comment: but there are lots of cells and once a cell is selected, it can be also deselected. So what I think is there should be a way to check all of the cells to see if at least one of them has 'UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark'

Comment: How about a variable that adds one for every select and then removes one for every deselect? If it is 0 then disable the next button.

Answer (score 0):

in didSelectRowAtindexPath  just check whether chemark is checked, if yes then uncheck it, if not checked then make checked it.

pseudo code ,not actual code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(checkmark checked )
    {
    un checked it
    nextButton.enabled=false;
    }
    else
    {
    checked it;
    nextButton.enabled=false;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you check the answer I wrote for Jens Hendar. Is it still possible for that kind of case?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I think the best method is to have a boolean value for each object.

I hope you have an objects array that you pass to your table view.

So, in didSelect method you can check in a FOR loop if atleast 1 object in your array is set.

Answer (score 0):

Enable multipleSelection in tableView. in viewDidLoad

> tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;

and every time you select or deselect a row, check for the count of `[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]` array's count. If count greater than 0, enable your button. Else disable it.

> [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] returns an NSArray.

No need of taking extra parameters than needed.